# Any Way to Tell Compiler Service to Point Out Unknown Attributes?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I've added a directive

```
<div my-directive>Hello, world.</div>
```

But I've forgotten to correctly wire in the actual directive code in my Javascript.  The app will just silently run without any visible errors, and it might take me a while to discover the mismatch.

Is there a way to modify Angular's compiler service to be more proactive about notifying me if it finds attributes that it doesn't understand?  (Anything that is both not valid HTML and does not correspond to any found directives.)  It might help illuminate configuration problems more quickly and directly.

Comment: `Anything that is both not valid HTML and does not correspond to any found directives` could be a custom attribute needed by some other framework or library(jQuery).